# React: stop page reload when I press refresh, instead show a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reload

When I press refresh in a page, I want to show this modal:
[image]

But I want to prevent the page to reload except if I click the `continue` button.

This is the code

```
import dialog from '@catapulthealth/catapult-dialog';
  .
  .
  .

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.showModal);
  }

  showModal() {
    return (
      dialog({
        title: 'We are processing your file',
        body: 'Importing will continue even if you leave the page',
        buttons: {
          ok: 'Continue',
        },
      })
    );
  }
```

dialog, comes from a private library. How can I stop reloading the page?

Comment: Can you add a debugger before you return in the show func to see if you can even pause the execution? Also, maybe try to remove the return... Maybe something like func for the ok button return true else return false, that might work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cookie once you clicked on Button, so when page reloads you have to check whether the cookie is set or not. On the basis of cookie, you can show hide popup. Please check following code reference.

```
import cookie from "react-cookie";

setCookie() => {
  let d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (minutes*60*1000));

  cookie.set("onboarded", true, {path: "/", expires: d});
};
```